# Simplify Repetitive Code Containing Multiple ifelse Statements

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I'm considering a potential policy change that will allow organizations (`OrgID`) to spend their existing grant money if they meet certain conditions. The data is three columns, and here's the first six rows:

```
 OrgID  Amount  Group
1     1 5782457 Group1
2     2 2280221 Group3
3     3 3260741 Group4
4     4 3869420 Group1
5     5 3950578 Group1
6     6 2058883 Group2
```

This would occur once per year, and the conditions are based on which group the organization is in (`Group`), and their current balance (`Amount`). Specifically,

> For `Group` = `Group1`
>    - If `Amount` is $500,000 or less, all the money can be spent
>    - If `Amount` is greater than $500,000, 50% of the money can be spent.
>
> For `Group` = `Group2`
>    - if `Amount` is $300,000 or less, all the money can be spent
>    - If `Amount` is greater than $300,000, 30% of the money can be spent.
>
> For `Group` = `Group3`
>    - If `Amount` is $100,000 or less, all the money can be spent
>    - If `Amount` is greater than $100,000, 10% of the money can be spent.
>
> For `Group` = `Group4`
>    - No money can be spent under any conditions.

I wanted to know the total money remaining after each year for the next five years, so I turned to the dplyr package and wrote the following:

```
mydata <-
    mydata %>%
    mutate(ReleaseOne =
               ifelse(Group == "Group1",
                      ifelse(Amount <= 500000, Amount,
                             round(Amount*0.50, 2)),
                      ifelse(Group == "Group2",
                             ifelse(Amount <= 300000, Amount,
                                    round(Amount*0.30, 2)),
                             ifelse(Group == "Group3",
                                    ifelse(Amount <= 100000, Amount,
                                           round(Amount*0.10, 2)), 0)))) %>%
    mutate(RemainOne =
               Amount - ReleaseOne)
...
mydata <-
    mydata %>%
    mutate(ReleaseFive =
               ifelse(Group == "Group1",
                      ifelse(RemainFour <= 500000, RemainFour,
                             round((RemainFour)*0.50, 2)),
                      ifelse(Group == "Group2",
                             ifelse(RemainFour <= 300000, RemainFour,
                                    round((RemainFour)*0.30, 2)),
                             ifelse(Group == "Group3",
                                    ifelse(RemainFour <= 100000, RemainFour,
                                           round((RemainFour)*0.10, 2)), 0)))) %>%
    mutate(RemainFive =
               RemainFour - ReleaseFive)
```

Hence, I just repeated the same block of code five times, but each time I changed the names of the variables that begin with "Release" and "Remain" (i.e. `RemaimOne` to `RemainTwo`, `ReleaseOne` to `ReleaseTwo`, etc.).

Doing it this way is fine but it got pretty messy. Is there a way to simplify this with custom functions, possibly including `for` and `while` loops, for example?

Also, it would be valuable to know how how many years it would be until all organizations in groups 1, 2, and 3 reached `Amount = 0`; but, the only way I know how to do it is keep repeating what's above until the amounts reach zero.

The data is named mydata.txt and can be found on GitHub at [this link](https://github.com/rymatt830/Data/blob/master/mydata.txt).

Comment: Please include all the relevant information in your post. Linking to offsite resources can result in dead links without advanced warning, rendering this question useless for future generations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate data frame to compare with-

```
grp_data <- data.frame("Group" = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4"),
                       "threshold" = c(500000,300000,100000,0),
                       "percent" = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0))
mydata$allowed <- sapply(seq(nrow(mydata)), function(x)
                         {
                          ifelse(mydata[x, "Amount"] >= 
                                 grp_data[grp_data$Group == mydata[x, "Group"], "threshold"],
                                 grp_data[grp_data$Group == mydata[x, "Group"], "percent"] * mydata[x, "Amount"],
                                 mydata[x, "Amount"])
                         })
```

Comment: Thanks, @code_is_entropy, but that produces unexpected results. For example, the first row contains a value of `c(2891228.5, 2891228.5, 2891228.5, 2891228.5)`

Comment: Sorry i just fixed the bug. Since there is no data, I could not test the code. But it should be okay now.

Comment: The data is linked to at the bottom of the question

Comment: I appreciate your attempts, @code_is_entropy, but there's still an error resulting in several `NA` values.

Comment: I did not see the link earlier. Having the data helps. I have tested the code on the data and it works now.

Comment: Thanks again, @code_is_entropy, but my primary issue is that I need to determine the remaining amounts after each year for several years. Your code isn't simpler that my solution because I can't rely on a static `Amount` field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little function that should do the trick - I made it slightly more general as well. It doesn't round, but I'm sure you can edit that in if you'd like.

```
extrap = function(data,
                  threshhold = c(5e5, 3e5, 1e5, 0),
                  below = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                  above = c(.5, .3, .1, 0),
                  n = 4) {
    res = list()
    x = data$Amount
    g = as.numeric(data$Group)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        x = x * above[g] ^ (x > threshhold[g]) * below[g] ^ (x <= threshhold[g])
        res[[i]] = x
    }
    names(res) = paste0("Release_", 1:n)
    return(bind_cols(data, res))
}
```

Running it on the `head` of the data you shared in the question:

```
extrap(dd)
#   OrgID  Amount  Group Release_1  Release_2 Release_3 Release_4
# 1     1 5782457 Group1 2891228.5 1445614.25 722807.12 361403.56
# 2     2 2280221 Group3  228022.1   22802.21  22802.21  22802.21
# 3     3 3260741 Group4       0.0       0.00      0.00      0.00
# 4     4 3869420 Group1 1934710.0  967355.00 483677.50 483677.50
# 5     5 3950578 Group1 1975289.0  987644.50 493822.25 493822.25
# 6     6 2058883 Group2  617664.9  185299.47 185299.47 185299.47
```

It relies on `Group` being a `factor` in the data frame, and that the `threshhold`, `below`, and `above` input vectors correspond to the levels of the `Group` factor. To make it more general I added a `below` vector, which in  your case always 0? I'm a little confused by `Group4`, maybe the `above` value should be `1`? I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This doesn't produce exactly what I'm looking for. Take row 6, for example, `Release_2` should be calculated as follows: `(Amount - Release_1)*0.30`. `Release_3` would be, `(Amount - Release_1 - Release_2)*0.30`. So each release is dependent on the original `Amount` and all prior `Release`'s. Once the threshold is met, the entire remaining balance will be released.

I provided the desired output at this [link to Git Hub](https://github.com/rymatt830/Data/blob/master/mydata_release.txt)

Comment: Thank you for the response. This doesn't produce exactly what I'm looking for. Take row 6, for example, `Release_2` should be calculated as follows: `(Amount - Release_1)*0.30`. `Release_3` would be, `(Amount - Release_1 - Release_2)*0.30`. So each release is dependent on the original `Amount` and all prior `Release`'s. Once the threshold is met, the entire remaining balance will be released.

I provided the desired output at this [link to Git Hub](https://github.com/rymatt830/Data/blob/master/mydata_release.txt)

Comment: I'm sorry it's not exactly what you're looking for as-is, but I think the method is pretty clear. Surely you can work out the details yourself?